# How to enable tag auto closing in LightTable?

Tags: html, autocomplete, tags, lighttable, auto-close

By tag auto closing I mean that when I add the `<p>` tag for instance, the editor should automatically put `</p>` after it, leaving the cursor between them so I can add text.

Ideally, in case of some tags like `<div>`, upon completing the opening `<div>` tag, the editor would insert a new line and move the cursor at its beginning (auto-indenting while dooing it) and would add the closed `</div>` tag to a third line, leaving the cursor on the second line for me to add content.

How to make LightTable behave like that?